# multiplication law vs addition and dice

Tags: probability, statistics

I know that it is possible to find the probability of throwing $2$ sixs using $p(6,6)=\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}$ but is it possible to use the law

> $$p(a \cap b)= p(a)+p(b)-p(a \cup b)\,? $$

Comment: Not really. The law you wrote down is correct. However, I cannot see any good way of evaluating $\Pr(A\cup B)$ without going through something equivalent to $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)\Pr(B)$. (We can write this because $A$ and $B$ are independent.)

Comment: @jimmy you wrote "P(A and B)".It should be "P(A or B)"

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding the mutually exclusive events a=2 sixes, b=only 1 six, c=no sixes but my enumeration is off. 1 way to get a, 10 for b and 25 for c giving .... Nevermind that's right

Comment: @Jimmy: it works just fine; it just doesn't help you because you'd need to calculate $p(a\cup b)$, and the only direct way I see to calculate that would be to list out all 36 possibilities and count...

Answer (score 1):

The law you wrote down is correct. But to use it, we would need to know $\Pr(A\cup B)$.

I cannot see any good way of evaluating $\Pr(A\cup B)$ without going through something equivalent to $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)\Pr(B)$. (We can write this because $A$ and $B$ are independent.)

**Remark:** We could try to be sneaky, and find the probability that $A\cup B$ **doesn't** happen. This is $\frac{5}{6}\cdot\frac{5}{6}$, so $\Pr(A\cup B)=1-\frac{5}{6}\cdot\frac{5}{6}$. However, we still have used a "multiplication rule," though in a more complicated way.

Comment: For example, Getting one six isn't a subset of getting two sixes. There is no cancellation no subtraction

Comment: I thought the probability of getting one six is 10/36 by just counting the ways (6,1)...(1,6) ...(5,6).

Comment: Yes I believe that doesn't work I'm confusing "and" in ordinary language and the intersection

Comment: The system is objecting to the long string of comments, so I will delete most of mine, and suggest you do the same. That will leave room for more questions, if any. Yes, the logical "and" and ordinary and are not quite the same, though the situation is far worse with "or".